# What's up with the visitors / day metric?

Tags: discussion, support

A week or two ago, this site was at around 1000 visitors / day.  Just now I saw that it was showing 2 visitors / day.  Huh?  I can't imagine traffic just magically dried up for no apparent reason. Is there a problem with the collection of the metrics data, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with all Stack Exchange sites currently: [Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51). SE employees are aware of it, but apparently it takes some time to fix the analytics.

Comment: Could it be possible that it is instead measuring *unique* visitors on only the home page?